# App Goes Background When MainActivity Class Called

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm learning Android Development with multiple app's source codes. I opened one of my projects in Android Studio. I developed some part of this app using some open source libraries from GitHub. My problem is app is compiling and I'm able to build APK but when I run it on a device the goes to background (not crashed because when I checked the logcat there is no trace for a crash).

When I'm running the app firstly the SplashScreen class getting loaded (There is no issue with it). After splash screen loaded it should open MainActivity class but it goes to background (As I already said that's not even a crash)

Here's SplashActivity's code :

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {

private void runSplash() {
    new CountDownTimer(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3), 100) {
        public void onTick(long j) {
         onFinish()

            }

        public void onFinish() {
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(new      Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }


    }.start();
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    runSplash();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

**UPDATE:** The issue is now resolved. The problem is with exception handling inside the onCreate method. Whatever exception happens then the activity getting finished (`finish();`). Thanks for helping me to understand.

After Splash Activity finished MainActivity Should be shown but the app goes background. I even tried ignoring Splash Activity and just MainActivity as a Launcher in Manifest file. But the same problem (As soon as app launched it goes to background)

Comment: Remove `onFinish()` from `onTick()`

Comment: Your whole `onCreate()` is wrapped in `try {...} catch(...) { finish(); }` - if something goes wrong in those ~ 150 lines, it will just close the app without telling you what happened. I'd say it's better to let it crash and see the error than to catch the error without really handling it (your app will close anyway)

Comment: @Markaos Let me clear that and try.

Comment: @Markaos Thank you my friend. Thanks for letting me know about this. I wasted two days.

Comment: Glad to know it helped you

Comment: Yes @Markaos the issue was solved now. Can you upvote the question if it is good.!

Comment: Please don't just link to code off-site. You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: I understand your question perfectly. I downvoted it because it does not meet the standards here. All relevant code must be in the question itself, not just linked to off-site.

Comment: I put the link because the code is too long and I don't know where the issue is that's why I gave link to it. When I paste whole code here it'll look awefull question. I'm unable to post specific code because I don't know where the issue is.

Comment: That's why you need to create a [mcve] before posting a question here. Please do read through that page.

Comment: @MikeM. what about now? I removed the unwanted part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity onCreate(), you've a huge try/catch block, and if an Exception raise, you finish() the activity...

You have to log the Exception with `Log.e("YOUR_TAG", e.getMessage())` to understand your bug :)

Comment: Well @Markaos and You said correct solution. Thanks for both of you.